# Make a dynamic sized bubble view with Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Below image shows example for Bubble view we need to implement.
[image]

We need to implement it using `UIScrollView` or `UICollectionView` or any other (if suggested how?)
Each Bubble represents a button or might have an event attached to it.

Is it possible to achieve this layout using above Elements.

***NOTE: we do not need to implement it using SpriteKit / SceneKit.***

---

we are having two kinds of circles here

- small - (radius 30px).
- large - (radius 50 px).

I guess that might help in calculations.

---

Comment: You have to a lot of work to do so...Make UIButton and assign each UIBUtton random animation and when their frame Intersects put all UIButton in on UIVIew then animate that UIVIew

Comment: What is the logic/pattern to know what circle is big/small?

Comment: we are having two kinds of circles here - small(radius 30px) & large(radius 50 px). I guess that might help in calculations

Comment: @SiddharthPaneri you done with this kind of thing so please let me know i also need to do same thing . thanks in advanced.

Comment: hi @SiddharthPaneri have you got any solution for this??